# Node JS Discord Bot | Reading and Writing Config File

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am having a problem with figuring out how my NodeJS bot can read and write data to a config.json file. Apart from that, I do not know how to detect arguments sent with a Bot Command. Therefore my Questions are as following:

How to Read / Write Data to a config.json?
How to detect args sent with Bot Command?

Thank you in Advance :)
-Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a NodeJS discord bot as well and for importing settings I use the following. I have not found the need to write to a json file, though hopefully this helps solve the first part of your question.

*Code sample*

```
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        var tree = JSON.parse(data);
    
        token = tree.token;
});
```

*config file*

```
{
    "token":""
}
```

For getting arguments from a command, you can do something like this:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    const param = message.content.split(' ');
    const command = param[0].substr('!'.length);
    const arguments = param.slice(1);
})
```

Here is my main discord bot file with such code bits. It is pretty cluttered with other stuff so beware. https://github.com/NicholasLKSharp/DiscordJSMusicBot-SpotifyPuller/blob/master/main.js